# A Navigation bar with hover effect

Tags: html, css

I want to make a Navigation bar with a hover effect.

The goal is that when you hover over it there is more content.

However, when you hover over the navigation bar and there is content displayed, I desire more content to be displayed when you hover over that content.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X4mZ.png).

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean with a drop down when you hover?

I've created a codesandbox with what i think you mean

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-shockley-qosw6

html:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: No i want it that when you hover over Link 1 there is another Dropdown menu.

Comment: Ahhh ok i see, slightly more complex as you need to add some floats on hover to the current drop down items, css script explains this step by step how to create a drop down menu like that

https://www.cssscript.com/create-a-multi-level-drop-down-menu-with-pure-css/

Comment: Working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-shockley-qosw6 @Idunno